# Swagger is not working in Spring boot framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

It shows failed to load API definition for one service only REST services are working fine

[network of the swagger is shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3uvO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use spring security?
can you load json in swagger?
if you use spring security you must add swagger path in webSecurity config